# highchart line don't show line even when data points exists

Tags: highcharts

I have an issue with highcharts of type 'spline'

I've sent data to the chart and even that the data exist the chart line seems to be cut at random parts

more ever between null points on the graph a line is drawn(the drop on the 12/06/16 in the black series) so it isn't a null issue. and I've got no errors on my console.
this is my graph init:

```
getChartElement().highcharts({
                    exporting: {enabled: false},
                    chart: {
                        type: 'spline',
                        zoomType: 'x',
                        events: {
                            selection: rangeSelection
                        }
                    },

                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },

                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },

                    tooltip: {
                        useHTML: true,
                        formatter: function () {
                            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br>' +
                                Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %b %Y %H:%M', this.x) + '<br>' +
                                Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                        }
                    },

                    series: series,

                    xAxis: {
                        type: 'datetime',
                        tickPixelInterval: 100,
                        labels: {
                            format: '{value:%m/%d/%y}'
                        },
                        events: {},
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: vm.issueDate,
                            width: 1,
                            color: 'green',
                            dashStyle: 'dash',
                            zIndex: 5,
                        }]
                    },

                    yAxis: {},

                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {

                            turboThreshold: configuration.maxGraphPoints
                        },
                        spline: {
                            marker: {
                                enabled: vm.isMarkersVisible
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I can't seem to find a reason for the gaps in the graph. has anyone seen something like this before?

**EDIT:**
I've changed the image to another more concentrated , and added the data for this graph
[screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0rZQ.png) I should say that in the screen shot there is one point but there are a lot more around it, they should have option for a screenshot gif :)
the data:
"{"tags":["Series1","Series2"],"data":[[1483436500000,34.219906,56.668186000000006],[1483439200000,34.047556,57.155266],[1483441900000,34.068456,57.649016],[1483444600000,34.050936,58.448235999999994],[1483447300000,34.316396,58.039416],[1483450000000,34.546116,58.428616000000005],[1483452700000,34.743466,58.722346],[1483455400000,34.850176,58.737145999999996],[1483458100000,35.050486,58.115166],[1483460800000,35.002866,57.522126],[1483463500000,34.855796,55.661925999999994],[1483466200000,34.796566,55.579976],[1483468900000,34.914366,55.925126000000006],[1483471600000,35.037526,56.223866],[1483474300000,35.008276,55.952646],[1483477000000,34.938055999999996,55.601265999999995],[1483479700000,34.946396,57.74743599999999],[1483482400000,34.860726,56.422796000000005],[1483485100000,34.749856,56.456556000000006],[1483487800000,34.734536,56.02268599999999],[1483490500000,34.710696,55.649186],[1483493200000,34.755316,55.868066],[1483495900000,34.801966,56.07148599999999],[1483498600000,35.175086,55.311626000000004],[1483501300000,34.868296,55.749516],[1483504000000,34.498436,56.425416],[1483506700000,34.526066,56.405936],[1483509400000,34.495226,56.905456],[1483512100000,34.736996,57.665266],[1483514800000,34.403805999999996,56.243786],[1483517500000,34.445266,57.025186000000005],[1483520200000,34.474966,58.428715999999994],[1483522900000,34.225066,59.531206],[1483525600000,33.961646,60.677266],[1483528300000,33.786636,61.355536],[1483531000000,33.875166,60.646305999999996],[1483533700000,33.905626,62.193096],[1483536400000,33.937476,61.098146],[1483539100000,34.293316,59.28490599999999],[1483541800000,34.530886,59.912486],[1483544500000,34.782956,59.955256000000006],[1483547200000,35.121126,61.357696000000004],[1483549900000,34.718436,61.931906],[1483552600000,35.711916,57.322496],[1483555300000,35.475236,57.541686],[1483558000000,35.481466,56.810136],[1483560700000,35.040016,56.614756],[1483563400000,35.030556,59.863856],[1483566100000,34.920466,56.529756000000006],[1483568800000,35.050486,58.436576],[1483571500000,35.050486,57.734145999999996],[1483574200000,35.156616,57.434805999999995],[1483576900000,35.154466,57.73637599999999],[1483579600000,35.101836,58.059096],[1483582300000,35.051496,57.998926],[1483585000000,34.998855999999996,58.298096],[1483587700000,34.911516,58.426916000000006],[1483590400000,35.028296,58.00146599999999],[1483593100000,34.748786,58.137996],[1483595800000,34.739406,57.887506],[1483598500000,34.808656,58.491716],[1483601200000,34.785016,57.416966],[1483603900000,34.971316,57.39732599999999],[1483608700000,null,64.130136],[1483609300000,34.633606,null],[1483611400000,null,53.998146000000006],[1483612000000,35.536296,null],[1483614100000,null,56.150756],[1483614700000,35.490406,null],[1483616800000,null,56.581025999999994],[1483617400000,35.243436,null],[1483619500000,null,57.063676],[1483620100000,35.638996,null],[1483622200000,null,57.347356000000005],[1483622800000,35.638996,null],[1483624900000,null,58.504306],[1483625500000,35.940726,null],[1483627600000,null,58.529796000000005],[1483628200000,36.022656,null],[1483630300000,null,56.503736],[1483630900000,36.081686,null],[1483633000000,null,55.968286000000006],[1483633600000,36.372056,null],[1483635700000,null,56.637946],[1483636300000,36.719646,null],[1483638400000,null,55.93278599999999],[1483639000000,36.721016,null],[1483641100000,null,54.665316000000004],[1483641700000,36.902646,null],[1483643800000,null,54.823786],[1483644400000,37.109685999999996,null],[1483646500000,null,54.314856000000006],[1483647100000,37.317226,null],[1483649200000,null,54.75750600000001],[1483649800000,37.364876,null],[1483651900000,null,54.618516],[1483652500000,36.959966,null],[1483654600000,null,54.384485999999995],[1483655200000,37.191016,null],[1483657300000,null,53.986126],[1483657900000,37.354926,null],[1483660000000,null,53.833296000000004],[1483660600000,37.128735999999996,null],[1483662700000,null,53.708625999999995],[1483663300000,37.340576,null],[1483665400000,null,53.942555999999996],[1483666000000,37.298246,null],[1483668100000,null,54.327676],[1483668700000,37.344015999999996,null],[1483670800000,null,52.919466],[1483671400000,37.384856,null],[1483673500000,null,52.566205999999994],[1483674100000,36.876546,null],[1483676200000,null,51.773675999999995],[1483676800000,36.821936,null],[1483678900000,null,51.389706000000004],[1483679500000,36.769695999999996,null],[1483681600000,null,53.077135999999996],[1483682200000,36.648186,null],[1483684300000,null,52.533496],[1483684900000,36.490846,null],[1483687000000,null,51.950295999999994],[1483687600000,36.326346,null],[1483689700000,null,53.609016],[1483690300000,36.595346,null],[1483692400000,null,52.940315999999996],[1483693000000,36.005396,null],[1483695100000,null,52.44433599999999],[1483695700000,36.063386,null],[1483697800000,null,51.514185999999995],[1483698400000,35.950686,null],[1483700500000,null,53.019206],[1483701100000,35.888916,null],[1483703200000,null,52.924876],[1483703800000,35.708086,null],[1483705900000,null,53.430285999999995],[1483706500000,35.610226,null],[1483708600000,null,54.919156],[1483709200000,35.826046,null],[1483711300000,null,56.011066],[1483711900000,35.954396,null],[1483714000000,null,60.86370599999999],[1483714600000,36.206146,null],[1483716700000,null,63.932226],[1483717300000,36.553256,null],[1483719400000,null,65.751636],[1483720000000,36.376646,null],[1483722100000,null,66.588736],[1483722700000,36.469485999999996,null],[1483724800000,null,65.012736],[1483725400000,36.719015999999996,null],[1483727500000,null,64.805766],[1483728100000,36.722796,null],[1483730200000,null,65.033006],[1483730800000,36.890826,null],[1483732900000,null,65.026316],[1483733500000,36.523786,null],[1483735600000,null,62.355006],[1483736200000,35.250296,null],[1483738300000,null,61.885886],[1483738900000,35.068205999999996,null],[1483741000000,null,62.914156000000006],[1483741600000,35.159856,null],[1483743700000,null,61.454406000000006],[1483744300000,35.295906,null],[1483746400000,null,60.997966000000005],[1483747000000,35.431956,null],[1483749100000,null,60.864366000000004],[1483749700000,35.568706,null],[1483751800000,null,60.33397599999999],[1483752400000,35.612716,null],[1483754500000,null,60.226226],[1483755100000,35.638996,null],[1483757200000,null,60.695226000000005],[1483757800000,35.638996,null],[1483759900000,null,60.044976000000005],[1483760500000,35.747096,null],[1483762600000,null,59.267495999999994],[1483763200000,35.906606,null],[1483765300000,null,60.225086000000005],[1483765900000,35.473906,null],[1483768000000,null,60.19800599999999],[1483768600000,35.141326,null],[1483770700000,null,60.319676],[1483771300000,34.927346,null],[1483773400000,null,60.239565999999996],[1483774000000,34.828386,null],[1483776100000,null,60.844066],[1483776700000,34.708716,null],[1483778800000,null,60.570926],[1483779400000,34.583616,null],[1483781500000,null,60.19209599999999],[1483782100000,34.463946,null],[1483784200000,null,61.080535999999995],[1483784800000,34.531076,null],[1483786900000,null,62.448046000000005],[1483787500000,34.557726,null],[1483789600000,null,62.603616],[1483790200000,34.583225999999996,null],[1483792300000,null,63.707105999999996],[1483792900000,34.602586,null],[1483795000000,null,63.756426000000005],[1483795600000,34.631766,null],[1483797700000,null,64.362686],[1483798300000,34.585755999999996,null],[1483800400000,null,63.391046],[1483801000000,34.893546,null],[1483803100000,null,63.281465999999995],[1483803700000,34.780836,null],[1483805800000,null,62.069226],[1483806400000,34.830476,null],[1483808500000,null,61.197186],[1483809100000,35.012096,null],[1483811200000,null,61.948235999999994],[1483811800000,35.077906,null],[1483813900000,null,62.346136],[1483814500000,35.009746,null],[1483816600000,null,60.837086],[1483817200000,35.134366,null],[1483819300000,null,62.107156],[1483819900000,35.204375999999996,null],[1483822000000,null,62.358816000000004],[1483822600000,35.244596,null],[1483824100000,35.265586,61.764275999999995]]}"

Comment: There could be many reasons for the gaps. Could you include the data in your post?

Comment: thanks, I've edited the question to include some data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a lot of your values are `null` these will create gaps in your series. To avoid this, set `connectNulls` to true in your `plotOptions`, which will tell highchart to graph even when there is a `null`.

**API ref on spline.connectNulls:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.spline.connectNulls

Edit:

**Working example:** https://jsfiddle.net/y5ygdx2a/2/

Comment: Thanks! that was it

Comment: Damn, it still happens.
the problem isn't even the null values as it just doesn't draw a line between existing points, most of the gap isn't real it should have been drawn

Comment: I found the problem, your answer is the correct solution, but that was only half of it, I was using highcharts v5.0.14 on that version nothing really helped even though the conncetNulls parameter exist, but once I've updated our version to the latest version the solution worked like a charm.
Thanks a lot,you rock!